# Calculating total Balance of Particular Suburb C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

```
   List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    int id = 0;
    int click = -1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer rec1 = new Customer("C0020", "Alfred", "Campbelltown", 1500, 2006);
        Customer rec2 = new Customer("C0021", "Ryder", "Liverpool", 2000, 2008);
        Customer rec3 = new Customer("C0022", "Alison", "Strathfield", 5500, 2012);
        Customer rec4 = new Customer("C0023", "Eliza", "Liverpool", 6000, 2012);
        Customer rec5 = new Customer("C0024", "Natsu", "Campbelltown", 2560, 2011);

        customers.Add(rec1);
        customers.Add(rec2);
        customers.Add(rec3);
        customers.Add(rec4);
        customers.Add(rec5);

        click = customers.Count - 1;

    }
```

How do i calculate the total balance by particular suburb? I can calculate the total balance of everything by using the code below:

```
        double total = 0;

        foreach (Customer Total in customers)
            total += Total.Balance; //Total Balance
```

Any Ideas? thanks

Comment: Why do you ever mention `id` and `click` fields and not posing `Customer` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# >= 3.5 simplest way will be using LINQ:

```
customers.Where(c => c.Suburb == "whatever").Sum(c => c.Balance);
```

Sorry, you didn't describe your `Customer` props, so I've assumed them.

Comment: Thanks!! How will i call this like the total balance that i currently have?             totBalance.Text = total.ToString(); something like this?

Comment: Seems so =) Please **Accept** if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) and [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) each group:

```
var suburbGroups = customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Suburb)
        .Select(g => new { Suburb = g.Key, Balance = g.Sum(c => c.Balance) })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Balance);

foreach(var grp in suburbGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Suburb: {0}  Total-Balance: {1}", grp.Suburb, grp.Balance);
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`

Demo: http://ideone.com/TQcgE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `Balance` property in your `Customer` class

```
var bal = customers.Sum(c => c.Balance); // customers is the collection
```

Comment: Question: `How do i calculate the total balance **by particular suburb**?`

Comment: actually i didn't get what is suburb, if it is also field then `Where` method can be used to filter out

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Linq expression...

```
var balance=customers.GroupBy(g=>g.suburbname).Select(lg =>new { TotalBalance= lg.Sum(g => g.Balance)});
```